# OpenWrt: Find neighbors knowing their MAC address

Tags: openwrt, arp, host-name-resolution

I have an [Open Mesh access point](http://www.open-mesh.com/index.php/products/access-points.html) connected to the same router (an [Aerohive BR100](http://www.aerohive.com/products/routers/br100)) than an Axis camera. I would like to automate the discovery of the camera's IP from inside the Open Mesh sensor, knowing the camera's MAC address.

This bad Ascii art shows how the things are cabled:

```
+================= Aerohive router ================+
|    ____    ____    ____    ____          ____    |
|    [..]    [..]    [..]    [..]          [..]    |
|_____||______||______________||____________||_____+
      ||      ||              ||            ||
     Axis   OpenMesh     borrajax-pc        DSL
    camera  access pt.   (my laptop)     connection
```

The router where camera and OpenMesh devices are connected to assigns IP addresses in the shape: 
*10.200.255.XXX/24*

If I unplug my laptop (borrajax-pc) from the Aerohive router and connect it to the WiFi network provided by the Open Mesh sensor, my IP becomes 10.223.176.150 (which is ok, since it is an IP provided by the Open Mesh sensor, and that's my router/gateway... my *boss*, after all). Anyhow... at this point, I can ssh into the sensor itself (as I said it's my gateway):

```
borrajax@borrajax-pc:~$ ssh root@10.223.176.1
root@10.223.176.1's password: 


BusyBox v1.19.4 (2013-01-08 11:35:01 UTC) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

  _______                          ________             __
 |       |.-----.-----.-----.  _  |        |.-----.----|  |__
 |   -   ||  _  |  -__|     | |_| |  |  |  ||  -__|__--|     |
 |_______||   __|_____|__|__|     |__|__|__||_____|____|__|__|
          |__|  http://www.open-mesh.com ---------------------
 (c) Open-Mesh, Inc. All rights reserved.
 firmware-ng: fw-ng-r443
 Powered by these open source projects:

 http://www.openwrt.org    http://kokoro.ucsd.edu/nodogsplash
 http://coova.org          http://www.open-mesh.org
 -------------------------------------------------------------
root@BorrajaX_Test_Sensor:~#
```

But when I'm inside the sensor, none of its interfaces have an address like the ones the external Aerohive router is providing (10.200.255.XXX/24), so I can't see my neighbors in one hop (or jump).

Just in case it's helpful, here's a list of interfaces with its assigned IP address:

```
root@BorrajaX_Test_Sensor:~# ifconfig
bat0     
bat0.0  
bat0.1  
bat0.2     inet addr:5.17.32.120  Bcast:5.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
bat0.3
br-lan1
br-lan2    inet addr:192.168.83.2  Bcast:192.168.83.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
br-meship  inet addr:10.223.168.1  Bcast:10.223.171.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
br-priv    inet addr:10.223.172.1  Bcast:10.223.175.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
br-pub     inet addr:10.223.176.1  Bcast:10.223.179.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
eth0 
eth1 
lo         inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
mesh0 
mon0     
pub0
```

As you can see, none of the IPs looks like the ones provided by my router (*10.200.255.XXX*)

Now, if I find the camera's IP through other ways, and I find out said IP is, for instance, *10.200.255.204* this is what happens within the sensor.

```
root@BorrajaX_Test_Sensor:~# traceroute 10.200.255.204
traceroute to 10.200.255.204 (10.200.255.204), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  192.168.83.1 (192.168.83.1)  2.265 ms  0.608 ms  1.378 ms
 2  10.200.255.204 (10.200.255.204)  3.227 ms  1.265 ms  1.092 ms
```

So it hops through the *br-lan2* interface and "sees" it properly. I can even ping it.

```
root@BorrajaX_Test_Sensor:~# ping 10.200.255.204
PING 10.200.255.204 (10.200.255.204): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.200.255.204: seq=0 ttl=63 time=2.788 ms
```

But the ARP table doesn't register the mapping MAC <--> 10.200.255.204 (I'm guessing because it's jumping once through 192.168.83.1)

Is there any way of *arping* a "neighbor" when that neighbor is connected to the same router than the Open-Mesh device itself? Also, as I mentioned, the IP the Aerohive router assigns to the Open-Mesh device seems to become hidden somehow inside the Open-Mesh device. Is there any way of overcome this "hidden-ness"?

---

PS: If I do the whole thing from my laptop, it works fine:

1st: Verify that my IP belongs to the range assigned by my router (10.200.255.XXX)

```
borrajax@borrajax-pc:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:f9:dd:52:10:78  
          inet addr:10.200.255.205  Bcast:10.200.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.192    
          [ . . . ]
```

2nd: Check the arp table:

```
borrajax@borrajax-pc:~$ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.200.255.193           ether   e0:1c:41:30:ea:40   C                     eth0
```

No camera!!

3rd: fping to the whole 10.200.255.XXX subnetwork:

```
fping -g 10.200.255.1/24
10.200.255.193 is alive
10.200.255.204 is alive
10.200.255.205 is alive
ICMP Host Unreachable from 10.200.255.205 for ICMP Echo sent to 10.200.255.194
ICMP Host Unreachable from 10.200.255.205 for ICMP Echo sent to 10.200.255.19
[ . . . ]
```

4rd: Check the arp table again:

```
borrajax@borrajax-pc:~$ arp -n | grep -v "incomplete"
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.200.255.204           ether   00:40:8c:e3:df:aa   C                     eth0
10.200.255.193           ether   e0:1c:41:30:ea:40   C                     eth0
```

Tadaaaa!! *10.200.255.204           ether   00:40:8c:e3:df:aa*  is the camera

Comment: This is kind of hard to understand.  The standard way would be to assign either a fixed IP, and/or a DNS hostname to the camera.  If your vendor doesn't support that, you should probably give up - either because they're too stupid, or they genuinely can't support it at the moment because of whatever this mesh stuff is doing.  Standard OpenWrt allows configuring fixed IPs for a given MAC (and then you can also add a DNS hostname for the IP if you want).

Comment: As OpenMesh puts it, I think you want a DHCP reservation.  http://support.open-mesh.com/knowledgebase/130/How-do-I-configure-a-Static-IP-address.html

Comment: Have you tried the Axis IP utility?   It is designed to do what you are looking to do.